# Dropdown list that takes people to the chosen page

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want people to choose from a dropdown list, and their choice takes them to a page they have chosen.

Comment: So what is your question exactly?

Answer (score 4):

In aspx

```
<asp:DropDown ID="MyDropDown" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="RedirectUser">
   <asp:ListItem Value="/MyPage.aspx" Text="MyPage"/>
</asp:DropDown>
```

In code behind

```
protected void RedirectUser(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   Response.Redirect(MyDropDown.SelectedValue);
}
```

Okay read the "question" again and you didn't specify ASP.NET but nevermind, more details in the question would have helped

Answer (score 4):

You can use something like this with a bit of javascript:

```
<select name='jumpMenu' onchange='javascript:window.location.href = this.value;'>
  <option value='Department.aspx?DeptID=0'>--Department 0</option>
  <option value='Department.aspx?DeptID=1'>--Department 1</option>
  <option value='Department.aspx?DeptID=2'>--Department 2</option>
  <option value='Department.aspx?DeptID=3'>--Department 3</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

If using ASP.NET MVC and Bootstrap use this code. All you have to do is name the Controller "without controller after it" that you will use and the action "the View" you will be using. It should work for you. Also if you aren't using MVC you can do the same thing with just the < a > tag with the href="" method. Hope this helps and I do realize that this is an old post, but I hate finding questions without answers.

```
<div class="dropdown">
        <button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Legal Links<span class="caret"></span></button>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a asp-controller="Disclaimers" asp-action="CopyRight">Copyright</a></li>
            <li><a asp-controller="Disclaimers" asp-action="AcceptUse">Acceptable Use</a></li>
            <li><a role="separator" class="divider"></a></li>
            <li>Terms &amp; Conditions</li>
            <li><a asp-controller="Disclaimers" asp-action="TermsAndConditions">General</a></li>
            <li><a asp-controller="Disclaimers" asp-action="ITTerms">IT Support</a></li>
            <li><a asp-controller="Disclaimers" asp-action="Microsoft">Microsoft Software</a></li>
            <li><a asp-controller="Disclaimers" asp-action="HostingServices">Hosting Services</a></li>
            <li><a asp-controller="Disclaimers" asp-action="ManagedTerms">Managed Services</a></li>
            <li><a asp-controller="Disclaimers" asp-action="Privacy">Privacy Policy</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```